# Create partition for linux mint in 1TB HDD

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, partition

I have a 1TB HDD. Using it for my personal uses.

I want to make a partition of 150GB (for LinuxMint19/Ubuntu) and 850GB (for file storing and usage in windows).

I want to know whether this is possible, if yes how to do it??

For 150 GB of LinuxMint19/Ubuntu, what is best option of space selection in LinuxMint19/Ubuntu? I.e. space to be given for /, /home, /root, swap etc.. I have 16 GB RAM in my PC.

When I login to Windows, I want to have access to that 850GB for saving files.

Pls help me on how to do it.

Comment: Please expand your question by adding links to the guides and recommendations you already read, as well as an explanation why they would not apply to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done without a problem. If Windows exists already, use Windows' disk management tool to create a 850G partition and leave the rest unallocated. Then, when you install Linux, you will tell the installer where Linux should go.

Because it is easy to make mistakes, I would install Linux **before** any data is written to the Windows partition, or if there is any data on that partition, I would create a **backup** of it first.

It's impossible to say how much you need for `/`, `/home` and swap, since nobody (except yourself) knows what you are going to do with your Linux installation. A separate partition for /root is not needed (and would be very unconventional).

However, the installer will probably create a separate `/boot` partition and, if your PC uses UEFI, an EFI partition as well. Both these partitions will be very small, much less than 1G.

You can run Linux without swap space, and if it turns out that you do need swap occasionally, you can enable file swap later. But if you don't really know yet what you require, I would just use one of the defaults offered by the installer. You are probably OK with some swap space, e.g. 16G like your RAM, the boot and (possibly) EFI partitions, and a single partition for `/`, `/home` and all the rest.